# http.get attempts to retrieve image when parsing when I do not need it to

Tags: angularjs

```
function getHTMLSource(url) {
      return $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
        var html = response.data;
        url = getDetailPage(html)
        return url ;
    }
)};

getHTMLSource('http://www.footpatrol.co.uk/s:282524/search=282524/')
```

Whenever I attempt the above code, I get the following error message in my console `GET http://localhost:9000/templates/footpatrol.co.uk/_assets/images/content/footpatrol_logo.png 404 (Not Found)`.

The image appears to exist at `http://www.footpatrol.co.uk/templates/footpatrol.co.uk/_assets/images/content/footpatrol_logo.png` but as I am running the scipt on localhost with Chrome's `Allow-Control-Allow-Origin` plugin, it appears to not play nicely. I do not want to GET the image I just want the source code, is there anyway around this?

**UPDATE: I think it might be my parser causing the problem, because the error message is thrown here**

```
function getDetailPage(html) {
  var temp = document.createElement('div');
  temp.innerHTML = html;
  var a = temp.querySelector('a[class*=\'fp-product-thumb-link\']');
  var partOfUrl = a.href;
  var splitUrl = partOfUrl.split('/');
  var url = 'http://www.footpatrol.co.uk/' + splitUrl[3] + '/' + splitUrl[4];
  var url = 'http://www.footpatrol.co.uk/' + splitUrl[3] + '/' + splitUrl[4];
  $log.debug('Detail page url found: ' + url);
  return url;
}
```

Comment: I don't see why this code would cause that error. What are you doing with the html you get. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I just parse it for information. Here is the log: http://imgur.com/a/Qxc5P

Comment: I'e updated the question with more details at where the error first throws. Could it be down to my approach to parsing?

Comment: Well, yes. You store a comple HTML document inside of a div of your document (which can't possibly result in valid HTML, BTW), so the browser tries loading all the images referenced in the HTML, just as if you copied and pasted the HTML in your own HTML document, without changing any of the URLs pointing to the original host's server. Google for parse HTML in JS (I don't have much experience doing that).

Comment: Remember to use `ng-src` in your img tag to get updated its value after resolved.

Comment: @aUXcoder I do not really need the img tag to be resolved, I would rather just keep the text to parse through without little regard for it. The error message keeps appearing in my console however and I would like to suppress it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating an element, use the [DOMParser API:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

```
function getDetailPage(html) {
      //var temp = document.createElement('div');
      //temp.innerHTML = html;
      var parser = new DOMParser();
      var temp = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
      var a = temp.querySelector('a[class*=\'fp-product-thumb-link\']');
      //var partOfUrl = a.href;
      //console.log(partOfUrl);
      //var splitUrl = partOfUrl.split('/');
      //var url = 'http://www.footpatrol.co.uk/' + splitUrl[3] + '/' + splitUrl[4];
      var elem = angular.element(a);
      var url = 'http://www.footpatrol.co.uk/' + elem.attr('href');
      console.debug('Detail page url found: ' + url);
      return url;
}
```

> Detail page url found: http://www.footpatrol.co.uk//footwear/282524-air-retro-15-obsidian.html